# Sending encryped messages using INSaNe. Messages not sending

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development, message

I forked INSaNe https://github.com/CryptoCoderz/INSN from github, changed genesis hashes, mined, and sended some coins between two localhost wallets. When i tried to send message from first address to second address i get this error: 
ERROR: SecureMsgEncrypt: Could not get public key for destination address.
How to fix it? I tried manually insert public key but nothing, still same error. Please help me!